# gedit text editor on ubuntu 16.04 lts

Tags: gedit

What is the command to understand from terminal that 'gedit text editor' is installed on Linux Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?
What is the command to install the same on Linux Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Comment: Please add output of `which gedit`, `apt-cache policy gedit` to the question.

Comment: And https://askubuntu.com/q/307280/158442. The package name is `gedit`, use it with the commands in these posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of understanding whether gedit text editor is installed on Linux Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is by typing in the terminal. NOTE: This is one of the ways to understand.

```
xyz computer:~$ apt-cache policy gedit
gedit:
  Installed: 3.18.3-0ubuntu4
  Candidate: 3.18.3-0ubuntu4
  Version table:
 *** 3.18.3-0ubuntu4 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Another possibility would be to simply try to launch it from the command line and see what happens. But be aware that while this is safe for `gedit` (as it doesn't do any harm when invoked by accident) it might be dangerous or risky for other applications.